# Since adding observers to my Ruby module, my system locks up

Tags: ruby, osx-lion, padrino

It only happens on certain types of errors, for example if I make a call to a method that doesn't exist on one of my objects.  But it's hard to get any information on what is causing this because I can't step through what is causing it, as my debugger locks up as well.  When I look at top, I see something like 97% of my CPU time being taken up by a Ruby process.  I tried running Sample Process in activity monitor to see if it could show me where it is getting stuck, but nothing relevant seems to come up (just alot of OSX classes).

This is a Padrino project, I am running Ruby 1.9.2 and using the Observable mixin.  I am on OSX Lion.  Any ideas or suggestions for troubleshooting?  This is killing my productivity!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of padrino do you have? Latest 0.10.1 fix this problem.